# SOQL query using LIKE and string list

Tags: python, salesforce, soql

I analysing data from salesforce using python and am searching for records with usernames containing 'Jack', 'Jones' or 'Jill' in them. The current, non-ideal solution that I have is:

```
sf.query(format_soql("SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE (Name LIKE '%Jones%' OR Name LIKE '%Jones%' OR Name LIKE '%Jill%'))
```

I have an example [here](https://simple-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/queries.html) and have managed to get the following example to work:

```
sf.query(format_soql("SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE '{:like}%'", 'Jones'))
```

However, I am unable to pass a list of strings such as:

```
str_list = ['Jack', 'Jones', 'Jill']
```

Is there a way to pass the list into the SOQL query itself?

Thanks, 
T

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this with SOQL but you might find Salesforce's other query language, SOSL more useful here.

For your use, the resulting query would look something like this:

```
FIND {Jack OR Jone OR Jill} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Lead(Name,FirstName,LastName ), Contact(FirstName,LastName )
```

So you should be able to manipulate your list into the above form.

For the Simple Salesforce library you are using, you'll need to use the search() method to perform SOSL queries

```
sf.search(<query string>)
```

SOSL Documentation Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm